# Wiki with API for creating/editing posts

Tags: api, wiki, mediawiki-api

Mediawiki is the only wiki software I've found that has an API for creating/editing posts (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).  Are there any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Twiki](http://twiki.org/) (here's a list of all the [functions available to the Plugin API](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiFuncDotPm)), or maybe the [DotNetNuke](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/) Wiki - since it's open source, you can do whatever you want with it (if you prefer .Net).